# jquery focus on input with aria-hidden

Tags: jquery

I need set cursor to some input and I use this:

```
(function($){
   $("input[name='login']").focus();
})(jQuery);
```

and it`s works fine)

But I can`t do the same with input, that within block with aria-hidden attribute that shows on href click.

Please, tell how i can fix this? Thanks for help!

UPDATE:
I fix it like this: click to aria-hidden:true and timeout for wait to opening form

```
(function($){
        $( "#clickFocus" ).click(function() {
            setTimeout("$('#authLogin').focus()", 600);
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input[name=login]").focus();

})
```